# OpenGL VBO without GLUT or GLEW

Tags: opengl, vbo

I am trying to create a 3D environment simulator of my own design using OpenGL, however my design requires me to have pretty much direct control of the run-time loop.

I am trying to learn how to implement VBOs in OpenGL, but I'm having difficulty finding adequate resources. From my findings, just about everyone uses FreeGLUT or GLEW or GLFW or GL3.h in some way to get around some of the platform-specific issues.

While these options may be great, I simply don't want to use other people's packages for this code. I would like to figure out how to use VBOs using the standard, vanilla OpenGL that comes out of the box on most machines. I could use some help looking for tutorials for VBOs in OpenGL that don't use any of these external packages.

...And before anyone suggests it, the NeHe lesson 45 about VBOs uses depreciated code (glaux) that doesn't even compile anymore, so that's not an option. :\

Edit: Maybe i wasn't being clear, or I'm being trolled, whatever...the point of the question was to find examples, tutorials, or other resources that teach VBOs in OpenGL that **DO NOT RELY ON THESE ADDITIONAL PACKAGES.** Seriously people, telling me to "give up" or "just use GLEW"...that's not helping.

Comment: Loading the function pointers manually isn't terribly hard as such, but extremely tedious. It's your time you're wasting though. Feel free.

Comment: I'm sorry, did you have a suggestion for a resource, or did you just feel it important to state the obvious that it's going to consume time?

Comment: There is no resource. And it's not just going to consume time, it's going to consume a *lot* of time *for no good reason*. Also, your attitude now makes me never want to help you. Ever. Which is a nice achievement - I'm usually not that spiteful.

Comment: The asumptions might be wrong, but the question is pretty clear and valid. I vote to re-open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you use VBOs is in no way different when using GLUT or GLFW and it doesn't matter if you load the function pointers manually (why would you do this in the first place? That's masochism, yes it can be done… but why should you?) or use a wrapper like GLEW.

I think you need your concepts right what GLUT, GLFW and GLEW actually are.

GLUT (old, Free… and Open…) and GLFW are frameworks: They create a window prepare it for attachment of OpenGL contexts, create an OpenGL context and then give control back to you (more or less). GLUT takes over the event loop. GLFW asks you for implementing a event loop. You can of course do the whole setup yourself. But if you do this, you need to have your feet firmly on the ground when it comes to he low level APIs of the underlaying operating and graphics systems. Better use a framework. You're not limited to GLUT or GLFW, there are others too: Qt, GTK+, SDL, SMFL, FLTK, wxWidgets, Fox Toolkit to name a few.

GLEW is a extension and function pointer loader library, taking care of the (really) gruesome details. opengl32.dll or libGL.so expose only a very small subset of all the functions offered by later versions of OpenGL. All the advanced stuff must be dynamically loaded at runtime. That's what GLEW is for, because doing it manually really sucks.

***None*** of them has anything to do with VBOs at all! If you thought that, you had some serious misconception.

---

#### Update due to request:

So how do you load extensions manually. Well, this is really nasty. First you must define the required function pointers in your source code. To help you with that, the ARB released a header files called `glext.h`. In this you can find lines like those

```
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC) (GLenum target, GLuint buffer);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC) (GLsizei n, const GLuint *buffers);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC) (GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
typedef GLboolean (APIENTRYP PFNGLISBUFFERPROC) (GLuint buffer);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC) (GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLBUFFERSUBDATAPROC) (GLenum target, GLintptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid *data);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETBUFFERSUBDATAPROC) (GLenum target, GLintptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, GLvoid *data);
typedef GLvoid* (APIENTRYP PFNGLMAPBUFFERPROC) (GLenum target, GLenum access);
typedef GLboolean (APIENTRYP PFNGLUNMAPBUFFERPROC) (GLenum target);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETBUFFERPARAMETERIVPROC) (GLenum target, GLenum pname, GLint *params);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGETBUFFERPOINTERVPROC) (GLenum target, GLenum pname, GLvoid* *params);
```

those provide you types for the function pointers. So you include `glext.h` into your extension loader module

```
#include "myextensionloader.h"
```

And then for every f***ing function you intend to use you define a function pointer variable. But here's the important thing: Those variables are part of your program, thus you must limit them into your own namespace; you can't just use names that may be present otherwise. So they won't be called `gl…` but something like `PROGRAMNAME_PRIVATE_gl…`.

```
PFNBINDBUFFERPROC myprogram_PRIVATE_glBindBuffer;
PFNDELETEBUFFERPROC myprogram_PRIVATE_glDeleteBuffer;
```

… and so on. You really want to do this with the huge set of functions later versions of OpenGL have?

*Actually, that's not even completely correct for the case of Windows, as OpenGL function pointers are tied to the OpenGL context active. Multiple OpenGL contexts in different threads being active at the same time => recipe for disaster. Those function pointer variables actually belong into thread local storage.*

Then you add a function pointer loader, which for every OpenGL function required loads it

```
void load_extension_function_pointers()
{

#ifdef USE_WGL
#define GETGLPROCADDRESS(name) (wglGetProcAddress(name))
#else ifdef USE_GLX
#define GETGLPROCADDRESS(name) (glXGetProcAddress(name))
#endif

#define LOAD_POINTER(name) myprogram_PRIVATE_##name = GETGLPROCADDRESS(#name)

    LOAD_POINTER(glBindBuffer)
    LOAD_POINTER(glDeleteBuffer)
}
```

Anyway, now you want to make this available to other modules. So you have a header file `myextensionloader.h` which you use to include `glext.h`, supply your function pointer varaibles as externs to the rest of your program and have a large set of C preprocessor macros that pretty-name your private function names into OpenGL function names:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MYEXTENSIONLOADER_H
#define MYEXTENSIONLOADER_H

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

extern PFNBINDBUFFERPROC myprogram_PRIVATE_glBindBuffer;
#define glBindBuffer myprogram_PRIVATE_glBindBuffer;
extern PFNDELETEBUFFERPROC myprogram_PRIVATE_glDeleteBuffer;
#define glDeleteBuffer myprogram_PRIVATE_glDeleteBuffer;
```

And this scheme still misses some details: In Windows the function pointers are actually tied to the active OpenGL context, so technically you need to somehow override wglMakeCurrent to update all the function pointers when the context is switched. And since different OpenGL contexts can be active in different threads those function pointers actually ought to be in *thread local storage* (TLS) to be correct. GLX is much more sane, but still you might be running on a machine with multiple X servers on different GPU vendors, so you've to cope with different libGL.so and libGLX.so and what can bite you there.

You really want to take care about all of this yourself? If you are the only user of that code, why? Really why? The process of writing all this is so tedious that the maintainers of GLEW never wrote any line of the actual GLEW library themself. What they did was writing a code generator that automatically produces the library source code from the specification files.

Comment: Thanks for the completely unhelpful response. I'm aware that none of them do anything with VBOs. I'm trying to get a VBO tutorial up and running, but using standard vanilla OpenGL, I get an error stating that "glGenBuffers is not specified." When you Google that error, you get thousands of answers saying, "install and use GLEW," which also isn't very helpful.

Comment: @user1731740: You really want to go through the lengths of loading the function pointers properly in a manual way? You're writing a tutorial, so why readers with this tedious process?

Comment: Yes, I want to go through the lengths of it, no i'm not writing a tutorial for others, I'm writing a simulation engine for myself as a hobby.

Comment: @user1731740: On your demand see my answer update. But seriously: Why?

Comment: Wow, I was hoping just to be pointed in the right direction, you didn't have to write the explanation yourself, but thank you either way. This has given me the necessary springboard of information to continue my path. THAT was amazingly helpful. Thank you.      As for the why, throughout the duration of my hobbist project, I've had three IDEs go obsolete on me, OpenGL has been revised twice as well. I'm starting to lose progress because external dependencies are forcing me to stop and re-write code. Im hitting a point where I just want to use my own code, and rely less on other groups.

Comment: @user1731740: If external references are causing you problems, then you need to rethink the way to organize your code. Having a library like GLEW being a dependency should cause you no trouble at all. If it does, you're doing something wrong. Note that you can compile GLEW statically; that actually allows you to add GLEW into your own projects source tree, as if it were part of your own project – of course just having it installed development system wide and only linking it statically is the better solution, as it allows for easier library updates.

Comment: @user1731740: On the topic how to cope with external references, I always recommend people to look at how Blender does it. The Blender source tree includes all external dependencies. When doing a build of Blender it can be configured to first create custom builds of all those libraries which are then private to the Blender build. The result is a truly portable build without any dependencies on system wide installed libraries (except those to APIs to the kernel and drivers). GLEW is among those external libraries which can be included in the Blender private build.

Comment: So if GLEW is so pervasive and wide-spread everywhere, why isn't it included stock into all OpenGL distributions? Why is it so difficult to add it to common IDEs like Code::Blocks? From the comments I've been reading, saying things like, "Why is GLEW so frustrating to install, its making me want to just stick to GL1.2!" The more I research it, the more of a pain in the ass it appears to be, as well as the more cryptic and high-level responses there are

Comment: @user1731740: Because there is no such thing like a "OpenGL distribution". People who struggle with installing a library like GLEW usually try thing they shouldn't. If you're developing on Linux you just install the GLEW development files from the package manager. If you're on Windows, the best course of action is to fetch the source code (not pre-built binaries, that's where most people mess up, choosing the wrong build, not matching their compiler/linker) and build it yourself (GLEW comes with ready to use project files/solutions). On MacOS X there's little need for GLEW at all.

Comment: Because there is no such thing like a "OpenGL distribution". I can install windows, or linux, or mac and just do "#include <GL/gl.h> THATS the common distribution. If I do not have to hunt it down and install it, it is commonly distributed. What am I missing here?

Comment: Now where to put development libraries on Windows? Personally I put them to C:\local\$BUILDSYSTEM\{src,lib,include} more or less matching the way it's done on *nix systems. $BUILDSYSTEM are actually several directories, like x86_64-windows-mingw or x86_64-windows-mvcc. Then I configure my IDEs to add the directories there, matching the used build toolchain, to the default search locations for includes, libraries and the like.

Comment: @user1731740: Well, we're talking about compiler distributions here, not OpenGL. Things are however not black and white. Compilers normally come with what's available on their target OS by default. Windows ever since NT-4 came with OpenGL support (NT-4 OpenGL-1.1, and since Windows 7 OpenGL-1.4). So since some (old) OpenGL version is part of what Windows offers, all compilers for the Windows plattform ship with the required headers and linker definitions for that. OpenGL beyond version 1.4 however is not what Windows ships by default, hence compilers don't have it.

Comment: @user1731740: On *nix systems OpenGL is not part of the default system installation at all. On Linux for example you get your OpenGL headers and access library only by installing some driver (Mesa/DRI or NVidia or fglrx). Those then also put the OpenGL development files into standard locations. Now the GLX ABI (that's kind of the standard document of what can be expected on a *nix system when it comes to OpenGL) defines just OpenGL-1.2 to be present, so the headers installed cover only that there, as well. And again you need to load pointers manually there, too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my additional questions. You clearly know this technical territory far better than I. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1731740: It really boils down to the specification of what's supposed to be present on the system minimally. Anything other than that => extra hoops must be jumped.

Comment: @user1731740: Just to cover the last missing pice: MacOS X. Well, that's kind of a sad story. Back with OS X Tiger Apple decided they would base the whole graphics system on top of OpenGL. This basically meant that OpenGL was pushed down very far in the system. As a result one can not update the OpenGL version without updating the whole operating system. And in the OS X ecosystem development tools are tied to the OS version. And since OpenGL is tied to the OS, what's available is exactly defined. So targeting a certain OS X version targets a OpenGL version.